# Caliburn.Micro and WebServiceResult

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, caliburn, caliburn.micro

I'm looking for the correct version of this class for Caliburn.Micro

public class WebServiceResult : IResult where T : new()

The above signature is from the ContactManager example in the full Caliburn framework.
It does not cut and paste directly into a Micro-based project. There are too many missing classes to use this directly. Thoughts? or anyone know of the replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event though the underlying infrastructure is very different in Caliburn Micro (which is based on System.Windows.Interactivity), the concepts are pretty much the same.

Here is the CM version:

```
public class WebServiceResult<T, K> : IResult
    where T : new()
    where K : EventArgs
{

    readonly static Func<bool> ALWAYS_FALSE_GUARD= () => false;
    readonly static Func<bool> ALWAYS_TRUE_GUARD = () => true;

    private readonly Action<K> _callback;
    private readonly Expression<Action<T>> _serviceCall;

    private ActionExecutionContext _currentContext;
    private Func<bool> _originalGuard;




    public WebServiceResult(Expression<Action<T>> serviceCall)
    { 
        _serviceCall = serviceCall;
    }

    public WebServiceResult(Expression<Action<T>> serviceCall, Action<K> callback)
    {
        _serviceCall = serviceCall;
        _callback = callback;
    }

    public event EventHandler<ResultCompletionEventArgs> Completed = delegate { };

    public void Execute(ActionExecutionContext context)
    {
        _currentContext = context;

        //if you would to disable the control that caused the service to be called, you could do this:
        ChangeAvailability(false);

        var lambda = (LambdaExpression)_serviceCall;
        var methodCall = (MethodCallExpression)lambda.Body;
        var eventName = methodCall.Method.Name.Replace("Async", "Completed");
        var eventInfo = typeof(T).GetEvent(eventName);

        var service = new T();

        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(service, new EventHandler<K>(OnEvent));

        _serviceCall.Compile()(service);
    }

    public void OnEvent(object sender, K args)
    {
        //re-enable the control that caused the service to be called:
        ChangeAvailability(true);

        if (_callback != null)
            _callback(args);

        Completed(this, new ResultCompletionEventArgs());
    }



    private void ChangeAvailability(bool isAvailable)
    {
        if (_currentContext == null) return;

        if (!isAvailable) {
            _originalGuard = _currentContext.CanExecute;
            _currentContext.CanExecute = ALWAYS_FALSE_GUARD;
        }
        else if (_currentContext.CanExecute == ALWAYS_FALSE_GUARD) {

            _currentContext.CanExecute = _originalGuard ?? ALWAYS_TRUE_GUARD;
        }


        _currentContext.Message.UpdateAvailability();

    }


}
```